# What's up with the way ruby alters variables this way?

Tags: ruby

Sorry about the vague question.  I'm at a loss for words to describe this phenomenon, thus google wasn't much help.  Please consider the following code:

```
array = [["name", "age"]]
a = []

x = ["Joe 32",
     "Tom 45",
     "Jim 36"]

x.each do |line|
  name, age = line.split(/\s/)
  a[0] = name
  a[1] = age

  array.push(a)
end  

array.each do |x|
  puts x.join(" ")
end
```

This produces:

```
name age
Jim 36
Jim 36
Jim 36
```

which is contrary to what I was expecting:

```
name age
Joe 32
Tom 45
Jim 36
```

Why is `array` affected after the fact by modifying `a`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set `a` to a new `Array` object inside the `each`. At the moment, you're pushing the *same* `a` object to the array, which is why it's returning the same value three times. Even better would be to not use `a` at all and instead convert the code into something like this:

```
x.each do |line|
  name, age = line.split(/\s/)
  array.push([name, age])
end
```

You could make it smaller than that even by moving the `line.split` to be within the `push` method, but I think that reduces readability and doesn't explain what information you're getting out of `split`.

Comment: Yup, you have to understand pointers even when they're not called pointers.

Comment: This works, although I still don't understand why the original didn't.  I guess I'll look into pointers.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly more advanced, but to build on Ryan's answer, rather than doing

```
x.each do |line|
  name, age = line.split(/\s/)
  array.push([name, age])
end
```

, you could use the `map` function, and have

```
people = x.map do |line|
  name, age = line.split(/\s/)
  [name, age]
end

desired_result = [["name", "age"]] + people
```

This is a slightly more "functional programming" approach. I'm sure this is a very rough summary, but in functional programming, you don't modify existing objects, you only create new objects instead.

As an aside, if you wanted to verify Ryan's answer, you could use `object_id` on each of the objects:

```
array.each_with_index do |object, index|
  puts "Object #{index} (which is #{object.inspect}) has an object id of #{object.object_id}"
end
```

which gives

```
Object 0 (which is ["name", "age"]) has an object id of 10204144
Object 1 (which is ["Jim", "36"]) has an object id of 10248384
Object 2 (which is ["Jim", "36"]) has an object id of 10248384
Object 3 (which is ["Jim", "36"]) has an object id of 10248384
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I've been meaning to look into functional programming with Ruby.  This is great example of how to do so.

Comment: @jack: Enumerating enumerables is a series of blog posts that I liked.